# iframe and CORS depending on browers and device

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, leaflet, cors

I have a generic question which I am trying to get a bit of information on, as this is the first time I work (and crash) on CORS, Same Site, cross-domains and iframe concepts. Before I decided to add this post in SO I looked into the web but any proposal seems to be the right solution to the following issue.

**How the code works**:

I manage a map using Leaflet, that works with a bunch of HTML, Jquery and PHP custom codes. The map shows some data based on certain filters the user can select.
Any search the user is able to run can be also shared via an API I have developed, passing filters as a query string in the URL.
To simplify the whole job, I thought to provide iframes with src based on the filters the user has defined, so that users can embed a Leaflet map with the desired resultset on their websites in a very straightforward way.

Something like this:

```
<iframe referrerpolicy="origin-when-cross-origin" style="border:none; width:96%; margin:0 auto; display:block;" src="https://example.com/?param1=NICE&param2=TO&param3=HAVE" title="example.com" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups" allow="fullscreen" loading="lazy"><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>
```

**The issue**:

Well, the above iframe is not always accessible from end users!
Sometimes it is up to the device (laptop, tablet, mobile phone), with huge different behaviors with Android vs iPhone (Android devices often work fine, but with iPhones I never had the chance to see the iframe working), sometimes to the web browser if I am working with the same device (Chrome, FireFox, Edge).
Everywhere I read into the web seems that this issue is easy to solve, just by sending

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

and/or a cookie

```
if (PHP_VERSION_ID >= 70300) { 
    session_set_cookie_params([
        'lifetime' => 1,
        'path' => '/',
        'domain' => '.example.com',
        'secure' => 'Secure',
        'httponly' => false,
        'samesite' => 'None'
    ]);
} else {
    session_set_cookie_params(
        1,
        '/; samesite=None; Secure',
        '.example.com',
        false
    );
}
```

Other attempts were related to enabling Javascript and cookies in browser settings, as well as to include referrerpolicy and sandbox as attributes in the iframe.

Is there a generic rule to follow so that in 2021 iframes can be easily viewed although their src come from different domains? Why is there such a different behavior among browsers and devices? Why are some users able to see the iframe and some others aren't?
Many thanks for your help!